# send and receive data between 2 application in c++

Tags: c++, return-value

I want to write two c++ application the first one called "caller," the second called "processor."

caller application send a value to a processor. after that processor do some process on that value and return it back to caller.

I want to know the best way to do that.

so far I know how to send value from caller application to processor application but I could not find any way to return the value back. one of this way by using putenv() and getenv()

caller example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv, char** envp){
    char myvar[]="MYVAR= say something";
    putenv(myvar);
    cout<<getenv("MYVAR")<<endl;
    system("./processor");
    cout<<getenv("MYVAR")<<endl;
}
```

processor example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv, char** envp){
    char myvar[]="MYVAR= say something else";
    putenv(myvar);
    cout<<getenv("MYVAR")<<endl;
}
```

how to fix that to return value from processor to caller and if there is better way what is it. I am using Ubunut OS.

Comment: Type `man ipc` at a shell prompt.

Comment: @Chris I'm using 2 application in the same machine and the performance will be low if I use sockets. I want a local call or share memory between applications.

Comment: Have you measured the performance?  How do you know sockets will be slow?  There are no 'local calls' between applications.  Shared memory is an option; with it comes the problem of synchronization.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think ipc will work but I need to read more about it. also I need something not Linux-specific way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did not measured the performance. however, when I study network last year the teacher was saying sockets will use the 7layer to pass the massage even if it was to the same computer but local call does not need that. and all what I need is a good performance

Comment: The 7-layer OSI model of networking doesn't exist in a real network.  How do you know you need good performance?  Why do you need two processes?  Why not do it all in one process?  What are your performance requirements?  How much data are you transferring?  If an environment variable was sufficient to get the data to the other process, it is probably a small amount of data that you're transferring, at least from `caller` to `processor`.

Comment: "sockets" does not equal "TCP/IP" in any case. In the extremely unlikely situation that using a TCP socket causes measurable performance issues, try Unix-domain sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible ways to communicate between to processes, and which is best depends on a lot of factors.  Using the environment is basically only good for one-way communication, not bidirectional communication.  The methods available include:

- Environment variables (one way)
- Command-line arguments (one way)
- Pipes
- Files
- Sockets
- FIFOs
- Shared memory
- Message queues
- Signals
- Semaphores

Some are limited to processes connected by a common ancestor; others can work between unrelated processes, sometimes not even on the same machine.  Some mechanisms can communicate very little data (signals, for example); others can communicate large quantities of data.  Some require no synchronization; others require extensive synchronization.

Which is best for you?  We don't have enough information to guess.  However, your best choice is most likely between pipes, files and sockets.

Comment: OK.  Which platform are you working on?  Unix (Linux) or Windows?  On POSIX, there are three shared memory systems to choose between; I'm not sure what the story is on Windows.  You have [System V IPC shared memory](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmget.html#), [POSIX shared memory](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html), and [memory-mapped files](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) for shared memory.  There are other functions also required for each system.

Comment: Im using linux. and between this 3 which one is better

Comment: It depends on your requirements.  Since I don't know what you're up to, any of them could be used, but I can't assess which is best for what you're doing.